# Powershell -- how to play different system sounds?

Tags: powershell

When I do this:

I get an obnoxious beep.

When I do any of the below, I expect different sounds, but they are all the same.
How do I access the native sounds ?

```
[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Asterisk.Play()
[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Beep.Play()
[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Exclamation.Play()
[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Hand.Play()
[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Question.Play()
```

(note, I do not want to play a file... I am looking to play sounds native to windows)

Comment: If there is a space between Play and (), remove it. Otherwise it should work.>>>>https://powershelldaily.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/16-how-to-play-beep-and-other-system-sounds/

Comment: I'm getting the same as OP, except it's the screen-flash visual cue.

Comment: As for this... `I expect different sounds`. That is a wrong expectation. What you are getting/hearing, is what is supposed to happen by Microsoft Windows OS design/install.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a Powershell code issue or feature. It is a Windows OS setting.

***Your issue is because they are the default sounds, which are simply a pointer to a `.wav` file.***

If you want those to be different, you have to choose a different `.wav` file from the Windows folder where they are located.

> ***C:\Windows\Media***

So, as for your comment `***note, I do not want to play a file.***`, yes, yes you do; but just one that is already on your system default location noted above.

Just go to Control Panel and select `Sounds`, or right-click the speaker in your taskbar and select sounds. Either way, change as needed manually.

Your options then become [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep?view=net-5.0) ...

```
[System.Console]::Beep()
[System.Console]::Beep(1000,300)
```

or this...

```
(New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer $(Get-Random $(Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:windir\Media\*.wav").FullName)).Play()
```

Comment: Thanks!  Are the contents of C:\Windows\Media\ consistent on all win10 systems?

Comment: No worries. As for the media folder, more files have been added over the years. For example, `Win 7/W2K12R2/Win10 - (gci C:\windows\Media\*.wav).count: 46 / 46 / 70`, respectively. So, you need to get a small set you want to use and only those across your use case.